# Delphi + Firemonkey: parent dinâmico em componente criado em tempo de execução

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Tenho um `TForm` que permite que o usuário do sistema crie componentes em tempo de execução (`TButton`, `TRadioButton`, `TLabel`, `TPanel`, entre outros).

Essa funcionalidade está funcionando, porém agora surgiu a necessidade de que o usuário crie esses componentes levando em consideração um outro componente previamente selecionado no `TForm`, ou seja, ele pode criar um `TPanel`, selecionar ele, e sem seguida criar um botão dentro deste `TPanel`.

Até agora eu usava a propriedade **Parent** do `Form` principal e definia isso em tempo design usando o mesmo, mas de forma dinâmica não estou conseguindo fazer. Já tentei usando o `Focused.GetObject` que pega o objeto selecionado, mas obviamente ele pega sempre o `TButton` que eu cliquei para criar o componente e não o componente que estava em foco anterior.

Tentei usando o `FindComponent` pelo nome do componente anterior mas também não consegui.

Tela da Aplicação:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem algumas formas de lidar com essa questão. Vou explicar como eu fiz a última vez que precisei de algo similar.

Primeiro você vai precisar de uma variável que guardará o valor do último, vamos chamar, `container` clicado, que no seu caso ao que parece pode ser um **TPanel**. Quando a pessoa adicionar um component ao form, você vai ver qual o último TPanel que foi clicado, e se utilizar disso para definir a propriedade **Parent** do component adicionado.

A lógica seria essa. Recomendo também, afim de facilitar o entendimento do usuário, você pintar as bordas do último TPanel clicado, de azul por exemplo, para que o usuário saiba qual está selecionado. Se eu não me engano no Firemonkey o TPanel não dispõe de bordas, mas o TRectangle possuí. Se você adicionar um dentro do TPanel com a proprieade Align setada para Client dentro nele, você pode pintar as bordas.

Vamos realizar um exemplo prático:

```
type
  TfrmExemplo = class(TForm)
    Panel1: TPanel;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Panel1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    ObjetoSelecionado: TFmxObject;
  end;
```

Repare que no form eu tenho declarado em public uma variável **ObjetoSelecionado** que como eu havia dito, ficará responsável por armazenar o último painel selecionado pelo usuário. Vejamos agora o conteúdo da `procedure Panel1Click`:

```
procedure TfrmExemplo.Panel1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ObjetoSelecionado := TFmxObject(Panel1);
end;
```

Após isso temos o último painel clicado pelo usuário, e como eu disse nessa mesma `procedure` você poderia pintar as bordas para ficar mais claro. Agora vamos olhar o conteúdo da `procedure Button1Click`:

```
procedure TfrmExemplo.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  btnAux: TButton;
begin
  btnAux := TButton.Create(ObjetoSelecionado);
  btnAux.Parent := ObjetoSelecionado;
end;
```

Ao realizar essa ação, você criará um botão dentro do painel previamente selecionado, resolvendo assim a sua questão.

Comment: Sobre pintar as bordas, sim, você tem razão, no meu caso, eu coloco um tselector sobre ele e ele assume as propriedades do mesmo, podendo redimensionar da forma que eu desejar, isso já esta ok. Sobre criar a variavel para armazenar, sim, também tem razão, já até fiz isso, porém, minha duvida é esta mesmo, como usar o nome do componente clicado anteriormente e transforma-lo em FMObject para que eu possa usa-lo como Parent do outro?

Comment: Coloquei uma imagem na pergunta original, acima, de uma pequena parte do meu software, exemplificando como esta agora. Eu já adiciono os componentes, pego as propriedades, etc. Só preciso mesmo inserir um componente dentro do outro que já esta selecionado.

Comment: Modifiquei a resposta colocando um exemplo mais prático da lógica proposta. Da uma olhada por favor e vê se te atende.

Comment: Legal, antes de mais nada agradeço as formatações e melhorias na pergunta e resposta, vou passar para o projeto suas dicas e volto para pontuar sua resposta. Obrigado.

Comment: Resposta precisa e perfeita, pensei em muita coisa mas a resposta era muito simples. Agradeço pelo tempo que desprendeu para ajudar;

Comment: Maravilha, fico feliz que tenha lhe ajudado. Boa sorte!

Answer (score 0):

Somente para quem estiver com o mesmo problema, a solução é simples, da forma que o Pedro explicou acima também funciona, mas, para mim, o exemplo a seguir funcionou mais adequadamente à minha necessidade.

```
ComponenteCriadoRuntime.Parent := TFmxObject(FindComponent(edtName.Text));
```

Onde `ComponenteCriadoRuntime` é do tipo `TControl` e instancio nele qualquer classe que eu desejar. `edtName` é um componente do tipo `TEdit`que contém a propriedade `Name` do elemento que esta selecionado em meu form usando a resposta do Pedro acima.

Assim funciona perfeitamente.